# How to Escape Single Quotation Mark in String.format

Tags: customlabel, escape

I'm using the translation workbench to translate a custom label(mail's body) to English. In the message, there was a word "haven't". When I check the test email, the word showed up as "havent".

I tried using `String.escapeSingleQuotes(mailBodyMessage)` but it didn't work.

So I went to debug log and check the message retrieved from the custom label. It came out that the message I retrieved from the custom label also didn't have any single quotation marks either.

I tried changing my custom label to "haven\'t" (it showed up as haven\t) and "haven `&#39;`t" (it showed up as haven `&#39;`t) but nothing worked.

For now, I deleted all single quotes from my custom label but I still want to know how to fix this problem. Could someone tell me how to escape the quotation mark in custom label? Any help will be much appreciated!

**Solution:**

I used the code that @Ralph provided and confirmed that there is nothing wrong with custom label. Single quotes disappeared after I formatted the message with **String.format()**. I googled and found the solution [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008yzsIAA).

```
To get a single quote in the output of a string.format requires two escaped single quotes.
```

So I put `haven''t` in the custom label and now I got the correct formatted message.

Ralph, Thank you so much for your time. :)

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to this question rather than editing your question to include it. Answering your own question is perfectly acceptable here and in fact encouraged if you find the correct answer yourself or one you feel is better than the provided answers.

Comment: Plus, your solution of using two single quotes is what's required: Custom Label's value: `Account''s Preferred Contact: {0}`; Then `String.format(System.Label.CustomLabel, new String[] {'lw29'})` returns `Account's Preferred Contact: lw29`

Answer (score 5):

That's pretty strange, and seems like a bug since you don't need to do anything in this case to handle single quotes.

It's working for me when I did the following I created a custom label, A_Test, with a value of "haven't", and ran the following and everything worked as expected. Assertions passed and email received with single quote intact. Perhaps you can try this out and see if the assertions fail for you? If they do I'd recommend logging a case with support.

```
String expected = 'haven\'t';
system.assertEquals(expected, Label.A_Test);
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
email.setToAddresses(new String[] { 'ralph@example.com' });
email.setSubject('Expected: ' + expected + '. Label: ' + Label.A_Test);
email.setPlainTextBody('Expected: ' + expected + '. Label: ' + Label.A_Test);
system.assertEquals(true, email.getSubject().contains('\''));
system.assertEquals(true, email.getPlainTextBody().contains('\''));
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { email });
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried your code. It worked fine, too. So I looked into my code further and found that the problem occurred after String.format. That means I have to put two single quotes into custom label so that it could work fine with String.format. I will edit my post and put the solution there. Thank you again.