# Apostrophe in custom label not showing on Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I'm using custom labels to display messages in a Visualforce page. The label contains an apostrophe that isn't displaying on the page. Can I get the apostrophe to display, or do I need to reword the label to take it out?

The label value is: "{0}" can't be interpreted as a true/false value. Please check the box if this field is true.

The relevant vf snippet is:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!$Label.Error_Invalid_Boolean}">
      <apex:param value="{!wrapper.affordableUnitInput}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

I've tried setting escape to false on the outputText and adding \ before the ' in the custom label. Neither of those worked.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you may just need to double up the quote in the label text.

`"{0}" can''t be interpreted as a true/false value. Please check the box if this field is true.`

Based on this half-related question:
[How to Escape Single Quotation Mark in String.format](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46339/how-to-escape-single-quotation-mark-in-string-format)

Comment: Right. Single quotes are escape delimiters that prevent {...} sequences from being interpreted as format strings. We had this problem using String.format to make CSV output.