# Include single quotation mark in string

Tags: apex, string

I'm trying to add a single quote to the following code

```
if(txo.Target__c != null){
                       targetsToCreate.add(txo);
                   }else{
                       o.addError(' Please ask your Salesforce Administrator to add a target record, for the month & year of your Opportunity's close date');
                   }
```

so that my string is displayed as

*Please ask your Salesforce Administrator to add a target record, for the month & year of your Opportunity's close date*.

The above causes the error

> line breaks not allowed in string literals

Having found various 'solutions', I've tried `Opportunity''s`, `Opportunity\\\\'s`, `Opportunity\'\'s` and

```
" Please ask your Salesforce Administrator to add a target record, for the month & year of your Opportunity's close date"
```

but none of the above work.

How can I include the single quotation mark in my string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Escape Single Quotation Mark in String.format](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46339/how-to-escape-single-quotation-mark-in-string-format)

Comment: @VamsiKrishna as I mentioned in my question, I've tried the solution from that post?

Comment: Where the output is being displayed? Standard page or Custom page?

Comment: @Ashwani it's a standard page.

Comment: Well it is working for me. I can see the `'` in Opportunity.

Comment: @Ashwani how did you format the string?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna thanks for clarifying, I missed the string.format portion of that solution, I've updated my question.

Comment: I have posted it as answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This way it works:

```
trigger SingleQuote on Account (after insert) {
   Trigger.New[0].addError(' Please ask your Salesforce Administrator to add a target record, for the month & year of your Opportunity\'s close date');
}
```

[image]

AND

[image]

AND

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ashwani but as you can see, that's exactly what I've tried in the original version of the code and it's not working for me..

Comment: @AlexS can you repost the screenshot covering the more area of page? It seems a difference.

Comment: I've updated the screenshot, just let me know if you need to see more of the page.

Comment: I've tried the HTML alternative you've suggested but again, that's not had an effect.

Comment: @AlexS updated answer with one more trick

Comment: Thanks, just to be clear, I tried `o.addError(' Please ask your Salesforce Administrator to add a target record, for the month & year of your Opportunity''s close date'+System.Label.ErrorLabel);` but got the error 'expecting a right parentheses, found 'close date'.'

Comment: @AlexS It is incorrect. Put all the string in `ErrorLabel` custom label. Don't write `'  '` double aphs in String. It nedds to be in custom label. See my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26459/discussion-between-alex-s-and-ashwani).

Answer (score 2):

You can try using html-entity for the single quotation mark:

```
if(txo.Target__c != null){
    targetsToCreate.add(txo);
}else{
    o.addError(' Please ask your Salesforce Administrator to add a target record, for the month & year of your Opportunity&apos;s close date', FALSE);
}
```

---

**Edit #1**
Ofcourse, don't forget to set pageMessages component's *escape* attribute to false (as I forgot to mention it):

```
<apex:pageMessages escape="false" />
```

---

**Edit 2**
Sorry, being in a rush I didn't notice that it's not a VF page you're having problems with, but rather a standard page. In any case, just use the **false** as the second argument in the [addError(sObj, boolean)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_addError_2) call, as the second parameter "Indicates whether any HTML markup in the custom error message should be escaped (true) or not (false)."

Comment: It will be printed exactly .....Opportunity&apos;s close date

Comment: `&apos;` doesn't cause any errors and wasn't printed exactly in the output but again, neither is the single quotation. Could there be something that's reformatting the output? cc @Ashwani

Comment: @Ashwani, it will be printed exactly, unless you set escape attribute to false. Sorry I forgot to mention it.

Comment: Message is on standard page. `<apex>` tag can be used on custom vf page only.

Comment: Well in that case just use false as the optional second argument in the addError() call.